# PHP Date json_encode

Tags: php, json, date

I have an array containing some dates, but these dates aren't being formatted properly into a JSON date. This is my code creating my date and putting it into an array.

```
$tempDate = $dt->format("Y, m, d)");
$JSONDate = "new Date(" . $tempDate;
$graphData[$dateKey][0] = $JSONDate;
```

But when this is converted to JSON using json_encode, the dates have double quotes around them:

```
["new Date(2016, 08, 13)"]
```

How can I fix this, and get my dates to format correctly?

My whole code: http://pastebin.com/k2QSqtXb

Comment: The question is not clear, what is the expected output> and what is JSON date? the json is hust a data format

Comment: I don't see what you want to "fix" here. For a syntactically correct json encoded string that content indeed has to be enclosed in quotes. Otherwise it would be invalid. So what do you want to "fix" here?

Comment: Json does not define a representation for dates. See json.org

Comment: Why didn't you just create the `new DateTime` Object and encode it as an Object instead? And, **you don't  expect to get an Object with json_encode when you gave it a String Data to encode...**

Answer (score -1):

This is the line of code needed to replace a double quote with nothing:

```
$json = str_replace("\"", "", $json);
```

Comment: May I ask why you answer your own more than strange question?